# devstack vnc showing "access denied"

Tags: openstack-nova, devstack

I tried setting up devstack in a desktop that i have and I am running into few problems.
I created an instance but when I try to access it in the console I get "unauthorized access" exception. In the previous version of devstack  I was able to access the console in the UI.

This URL below seems to be having some issues:

```
http://192.168.0.10:6080/vnc_auto.html?token=d2da2ca250bb&title=u1(9f58-8f58ed778d3b)
```

I saw that the most recent version of devstack has the following vnc related change:

https://review.openstack.org/#/c/140860/

https://review.openstack.org/#/c/107073/

However, I am not sure if I should revert this change or is there a different way to enable the vnc?

When I grep for all the ports that are open and listening 6080 is not one of them.

I see following in my nova.conf

```
vncserver_proxyclient_address = 127.0.0.1
vncserver_listen = 127.0.0.1
vnc_enabled = true
xvpvncproxy_base_url = http://192.168.0.10:6081/console
novncproxy_base_url = http://192.168.0.10:6080/vnc_auto.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the service in local.conf file by adding the line enable_service n-novnc. And then run a fresh stack.sh which will download and start the novnc service.